# Feeling confused with -(--a) vs --(-a) in c

Tags: c, increment, decrement

Confusion with  **++** and **--** operator

```
int a = 10;
printf("%d\n", -(--a) ); // valid

output: -9
```

But, problem occurs when following is used:

```
printf("%d\n", --(-a));  // error, invalid
```

Why?

Comment: You seem to be interpreting -(--a) as a sequence of letters with some magical properties. Look at both, write down what exactly each expression is supposed to do, and it should be obvious why one is allowed and the other not. Just replace "--" with "pre-decrement operator" and "-" with "unary minus".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `++` and `--` operator works on only lvalue, not value. An lvalue is something that can stand on the left side of an assignment.

```
printf("%d\n", -(--a) );
```

Here, `--` operator works on variable `a`, so this is valid.

But,

```
printf("%d\n", --(-a));
```

Here, `(-a)` returns a value. `--` is applied to a value, which is not valid.
This is because `--` modifies a variable, and `int` value can't be modified (For example you can't do `7 = 5` but you can do `a = 5`)

Comment: Not only on variable, but on what is called 'lvalue' (named after being allowed on left side of assignment. For example `--*expr` or `--expr1[expr2]`, `--expr->field` are allowed.